# Add Google Play Services as a reference without IDE

Tags: android, ant, dependencies, google-play-services

I'm developing an Android app and I'd like to add Google Play Services as a dependency to my project. But I'm not using Eclipse or Android Studio or anything, I'm sticking with the bare files created by "android create project".

How do I add that library as a dependency to my project? I can only find references on how to do it by using Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the reference on your project.properties file!

Example:

```
android.library.reference.1=../../BaseGameUtils
android.library.reference.2=../../libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

Note that this path should be changed to match your environment!